# java client certificate authentication

Tags: jsp, authentication, certificate, cac

I implemented a strong authentication in a web server (apache) and it work great.
but I want to implement a java class that have to compare cac ID and suject name to the ones presents on java .properties file or XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about your deployment but for example if you need to do that from a servlet deployed in `Tomcat` you could do:

```
X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

If the client has send certificates then `certs` will have them and you can do the check you need and possibly reject according to your needs.
Note that this will happen *after* the SSL handshake has finished.

Comment: how can i manage or detect smart card removal event? and how to disconnect the client after.

Comment: @xfocus:You did not mention this in the OP.And I don't know how you could detect this.Depends on your client program?

Comment: my middleware application(gemalto classic client) can detect and remove client certificate from personnal certificate store,after the card is removed,but i don't know how to take advantage of that.

Comment: @xfocus:Perhaps send a message to server to indicate this happened?

Comment: i don't realy know how to do that.cose the classic client only remove the client certificate so how the server will be informed?

Comment: @xfocus:Assuming that gemalto (have never used this) is just a library to access smart card and you send the credentials via an https client, you could register a listener and on removal, send a "special" message to your server